# EC2 public DNS inconnect when putty connect exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using Ruby on rails with EC2 !
when I access EC2 from Putty and, type command `RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 80 -b 0.0.0.0`, It works(can access Public DNS)!
but if exit the putty, then inconnect and can't access Public DNS.

How can I permanent keep, even I type command only one time in putty and exit..

Comment: Can you improve the question. What you ate trying to achieve

Comment: sorry, and I found the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution,
just hit `screen` in SSH!
then, it'll activated another SSH, and type command anything.
after when you out SSH, then EC2 will Keep going on, not inconnect..

Comment: You should ask your last question again; I have an answer for you.